# Google Font Weight is fine on localhost but lighter on live site

Tags: css, google-fonts

I got:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
```

on my style.css and a standard:

```
font-weight: 800;
font-family: "Inter",sans-serif;
```

applied on all my h1,h2,h3.

The font looks totally fine when checking on localhost, but my live site renders it more like a 600 or so. There is no css on top of it, and I just tried to change the font in the inspect tool noticing that it only applies a change when moving from 500 to 600, then whatever number on top doesn't make it bolder on the live site.

Any idea why that could happen? Thank you!

Comment: Check your live site if all of those listed weights `400;500;600;700;800;900` made it into the `html` document. If not and it was changed recently, try clearing internet cache and refresh the page.

Comment: Yes, they are in the document. The font gets loaded correctly in the css as well. Tried from 3 different browsers with incognito and clear cache. 

It just looks it only wants to render a bold version and nothing bolder